# Laravel mix.js() Tranpiling My ES6 to Vanilla JS

Tags: laravel, webpack, babeljs, laravel-mix

My webpack.mix.js has:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

In my resources/js/app.js, I have:

```
var hello = () => {
    'use strict';
  alert( "Hello World!" );
};

hello();
```

After I run:

```
npm run dev
```

My transpiled js/app.js converts the above ES6 code to Vanilla JavaScript (no arrow function):

```
var hello = function hello() {
  'use strict';

  alert("Hello World!");
};

hello();
```

My question is: If mix.js() already transpiles ES6 to Vanilla JS, then what's the point of mix.babel()? I thought that was the whole point of using mix.babel() instead of mix.js()?

Answer (score 0):

You can put own babel config inside `.babel()` if you need more advanced/custom parsing. Probably `.js()` is bundle of `.babel()` and few other functions also.